# Using VBA to remove the alias name from an SQL query string?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vba, excel

I have an SQL query string. In this string are multiple different columns of data, all coming from the same table. For simplicities sake, here is a short example: `SELECT 'A'.'B', 'A'.'C', 'A'.'D'`
Where `'A'` is the alias name. My question is: Is there a way using VBA to take that query string, and remove all instances of the alias `'A'` and just return the data columns `'B', 'C', 'D'`?
Please no full code, I like starting points. I like to fill in the pieces on my own. It helps the learning process.

Comment: What is the purpose of removing those aliases?  If there are 2 tables with the same column name, your query will fail because it will be too ambiguous to the engine on which column to pull from which table.  The alias helps define which column is the proper one.

Comment: Your example SQL is misinformed.  Single quotes are not used for table and column aliases.  Also, tag your question with the database you are actually using.

Comment: I suppose I should have been more clear. I do know that the alias is important and needed when using the query, but I just need the `'B','C','D'` fields for other purposes. I apologize for the ambiguity. (still kind of new to this site)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks. I don't know too much about SQL. I just wrote that short example in the same format that the string I have is. I just replaced the sensitive information with simple letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Recover the SQL under the QueryTable like this:

**Recover SQL:**

```
Range("A1").Select 'Your query worksheet
With Selection.QueryTable
    queryText = .CommandText
End With
```

2. Then replace the aliases with `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `INSTR` or `RegExp` object (if you want to learn something useful and quick use `RegExp` - regular expressions). If you need an example regex let me know in the comments. If you want to learn Regex in VBA I made a [tutorial here](http://www.analystcave.com/tutorials/excel-regex-tutorial/).
3. Replace the query and refresh the QueryTable

**Replace and refresh query**

```
Range("A1").Select 'Your query worksheet
With Selection.QueryTable
    .CommandText = queryText
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Comment: Thank you. I do believe this is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Are you selecting straight from the table? Going straight from the table would give you the column name, unless you're performing some function in your query. Another option is:

Select [A] AS columnName, [B] AS ColumnName2, etc